# Connect to SharePoint and outlook using Azure Service principal/managed identity

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-managed-identity, azure-service-principal

I am new to Azure services and I am trying to replace the usage of a service account in my logic apps to connect to SharePoint and Outlook. I found in blogs that Azure Service principal/managed identity can be used here. I also understand that the SharePoint needs an user account to sign/connect. Can we connect to Microsoft Graph API using service principals which will in turn connect to SharePoint?
Is there any way where i can use the service principals/managed identity to connect to SharePoint and Outlook in my Logic apps?
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The out of the box connectors do not support managed identity but you could use an http action depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! We are trying to perform CRUD operations on SP and send basic emails using Outlook

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not supported but instead, you can try using an HTTP connector to connect your Microsoft Graph API using Azure AD or Azure functions and in the next step you can connect to your site using the Sharepoint connector. Below is somewhat how the flow looks like,

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[USING MICROSOFT GRAPH IN LOGIC APPS](https://martinkearn.azurewebsites.net/articles/using-microsoft-graph-in-logic-apps?msclkid=c24340a8d02511ec87cbc189b3b96214)

Comment: Thanks Shwetha! But the default SharePoint connector would need a user account to connect and i understand that Service principals are not a user account. So can we connect to SP connector with a Service principal?

Comment: @Spoorthy, As of now you can have only a default connection i.e.,  If the logic app is shared with another user, another user will be prompted to create a new connection explicitly. try checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#creating-a-connection

Comment: Hi, running into a similar issue, I'm a bit lost on how this helps, since the http call to microsoft graph doesn't seem to affect the sharepoint call. Any explanation would be appreciated, as I've been struggling to make the sharepoint connector work the way I want it to for quite some time now.